# why I can't set locale in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, localization, laravel-blade

I'm using the following simple codes to change the language in my laravel application, But it doesn't change anything. the language still the default 'en'

**Route**

```
Route::get('lang/{local}','LanguageController@setlanguage');
```

**Controller**

```
public function setlanguage(Request $request)
    {
        \App::setLocale($request->local);

        return back()->withInput();
    }
```

**View**

```
 @if(App::getLocale() == 'en')
    <a href="{{url('/lang/ar')}}">العربية</a>
 @elseif(App::getLocale() == 'ar')
    <a href="{{url('/lang/en')}}">English</a>
 @endif
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Using session stuff and `back()` sometimes yields weird behaviour for me. Try returning a view instead or something and see if it works that way.

Comment: it was the problem right, I didn't think of if because redirect to '/' didn't work either , but return view works. thanks...

Comment: it was the problem right, I didn't think of if because redirect to '/' didn't work either , but return view works. thanks... but i still loose the language once I go to another route. why?

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller function to

```
public function setlanguage($local)
{
    \App::setLocale($local);

    return back()->withInput();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `\App::setLocale()` it will change the language for this specific request and after you return `back()` the request finished, and the language returned to default value.

If you want to save this changes, save the language in the session, and add a middleware to change it if there is a `language` in the session.

Ex:

### Controller:

```
public function setlanguage(Request $request)
{
    \Session::put('language', $request->local);

    return back();
}
```

### Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (\Session::has('language')) {
        \App::setLocale(\Session::get('language'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it works:
App::setLocale($request->local);

Instead of this:
\App::setLocale($local);